# Spring MVC and Liferay - Resource Mapping issue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, liferay, spring-portlet-mvc

I came across this weird situation-

In my Jsp, I have

```
<form:hidden path="year"/>
<portlet:resourceURL id="image" var="imageURL">
   <portlet:param name="year" value="${bean.year}" />
</portlet:resourceURL>       
<img src="${imageURL}" alt="Image" />
```

In my controller I have a method

```
@ResourceMapping("image")
public void getImage(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response, 
  @RequestParam("year") final int year){
  //serve resource here
}
```

During execution,

> NumberFormatException is thrown : Cannot convert string [] to int
>   2013,2013

I found the soultion is to change the `portlet:param name` from `year` to something else, as there is already a hidden variable named year, for some reason the parameter gets passed twice in the request and fails to convert the value.

I would like to know why same parameter name is not acceptable if anyone has more knowledge about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in `<form:hidden path="year"/>`. With that code you put parameter *year* to the request and with `<portlet:param name="year" value="${bean.year}" />`  you put another one parameter *year* to the request. Therefore, you get array of *year* parameters in your controller and it is not possible to convert to int.

According to the code snippet of your JSP, I guess that `<form:hidden path="year"/>` is not necessary to use.